# Insert a list item using REST form webpart: 403 error even when X-RequestDigest is present

Tags: javascript, validation, rest

I intend to **insert a list item from the main page in intranet to a list hosted on another site collection**.

I made this simple HTML & JS to get it done, but I always get the **403** / FORBIDDEN error:  "The **security validation for this page is invalid**.  Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."

Page URL: `http://intranetv2/Incidencias.aspx` (site collection 1)

List URL: `http://intranetv2/teams/sistemas/Incidencias` (site collection 2)

Auth is standard claims.

Now this is my code, **it is embedded in a script editor webpart**:

```
<div style=" margin: 40px; ">
   <h3>Reportar una incidencia</h3> 

   <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"><\/script>')
   </script>

   <script src="/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js"></script>

   <script>
   var targetUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
   var apiEndpoint = "/teams/sistemas/_api/lists/getbytitle('Incidencias')/items";


   //var targetUrl = '/teams/sistemas';
   var listName = 'Incidencias';
   var listURL = '/teams/sistemas/Lists/Incidencias/';

   // Adding a list item with the metadata provided
   function addListItem(targetUrl, endpoint, listname, itemType, metadata, successCallback, errorCallback) {
       var targetSiteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

       metadata.__metadata = { type: itemType };

       var re = new SP.RequestExecutor(targetUrl);
       re.executeAsync({
          url: endpoint,
          headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose', 'X-RequestDigest' : $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val() },
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(metadata),
          success: successCallback,
          error: errorCallback
       });
   }

   function NuevaIncidencia(){

       var metadata = {
          Title:         'AA',
          Description:  'AA',
          'Tipo Incidencia':   'Problema de red, no funciona internet',
          Prioridad:      'Baja'
       };


       addListItem(targetUrl, apiEndpoint, listName, 'SP.Data.IncidenciasListItem', metadata, success, error);
   }

   function error (xhr) {
      alert('ERROR: ' + xhr.error.message.value);
   }

   function success (data) {
      var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response.body);

      alert('incidencia creada: ' + jsonObject.ID);

      window.location.reload();
   }

   </script>

   Título
   <input id="titulo" name="titulo" type="text" />
   <br />

   Descripcion
   <input id="descripcion" name="descripcion" type="text" />
   <br />

   Tipo
   <input id="tipo" name="tipo" type="text"/>
   <br />

   Prioridad
   <input id="prioridad" name="prioridad" type="text" />
   <br />

   <input id="Aceptar" name="Aceptar" type="button" value="Aceptar" onclick="NuevaIncidencia(); this.disabled = true; return false;"/>
</div>
```

**REQUEST:**

```
Remote Address:192.168.0.26:80
Request URL:http://intranetv2/teams/sistemas/_api/lists/getbytitle('Incidencias')/items
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 FORBIDDEN

Request Headers
Accept:application/json; odata=verbose
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:162
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:Ribbon.EditingTools.CPInsert=1920955|-1|1392|-1142501406; Ribbon.List=1920955|-1|330|905164056; Ribbon.Permission=1920955|-1|1472|2082598053; SearchSession=60b28d12%2D8186%2D4121%2Da4d0%2Df746bf476ccf; databaseBtnText=0; databaseBtnDesc=0; PWA_Perf=0; Ribbon.Read=1376808|-1|0|1699301174; Ribbon.WikiPageTab=1920430|-1|503|1699301174; Ribbon.EditingTools.CPEditTab=1920430|-1|593|-1142501406; WSS_FullScreenMode=false
DNT:1
Host:intranetv2
Origin:http://intranetv2
Referer:http://intranetv2/Pages/Incidencias.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
X-RequestDigest:0x9CAF12232FF74ECE20D646319A2FBC4D4D3983130A1D23495833A73FFCDC9A59C21CE4A465C14600C94C31E2DD3B8E1E78D2F7989F2DAA9BFE37EC501691BB58,05 Aug 2014 12:15:00 -0000

Request Payload
    {Title:AA, Description:AA, Tipo Incidencia:Problema de red, no funciona internet, Prioridad:Baja,…}
    Description: "AA"
    Prioridad: "Baja"
    Tipo Incidencia: "Problema de red, no funciona internet"
    Title: "AA"
    __metadata: {type:SP.Data.IncidenciasListItem}
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
Response Headers

Cache-Control:private, max-age=0
Content-Type:application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 05 Aug 2014 12:15:02 GMT
Expires:Mon, 21 Jul 2014 12:15:03 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 05 Aug 2014 12:15:03 GMT
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices:15.0.0.4569
request-id:4f84ab9c-4d19-3070-f7fd-b53939c67167
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
SPRequestGuid:4f84ab9c-4d19-3070-f7fd-b53939c67167
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN
X-MS-InvokeApp:1; RequireReadOnly
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-RequestDigest:0x69A556EF83654433A02D9DEFEA7A748C41D2D9C6803C2973B2341C661F1BF3BCB27C328D363271D61BF296D7938589CE032DB10376A0CBA87357022B944A1159,05 Aug 2014 12:15:03 -0000
X-RequestDigest:0x69A556EF83654433A02D9DEFEA7A748C41D2D9C6803C2973B2341C661F1BF3BCB27C328D363271D61BF296D7938589CE032DB10376A0CBA87357022B944A1159,05 Aug 2014 12:15:03 -0000
X-SharePointHealthScore:0
```

Using Ajax inside the addListItem (the params of the function are from later version, thus not thoroughly used here):

```
UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval)

$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/teams/sistemas/_api/lists/getbytitle('Incidencias')/items",
    type: "POST",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json", "X-RequestDigest" : $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val },
    data: JSON.stringify(metadata), 
    success: function (data) {
                if (data.d) { 
                   alert(data.d.__metadata.etag);
                }
             },
    error: function (xhr) {
                alert('ERROR: ' + xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
           }
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `RequestExecutor` library, that's only for cross domain calls.  And `X-ReqestDigest` is not needed when using `RequestExecutor`.

Comment: I tried with plain $.ajax, also I tried without the X-ReqestDigest field, wich the RequestExecutor adds automatically for you. also I tried with UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, _spFormDigestRefreshInterval) before the call.

Comment: What's your code when you use plain `$.ajax()`? Also, what's the internal name for `Tipo Incidencia`?

Comment: Edited the question with the ajax version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a way around! Using SPservices:

```
function NuevaIncidencia(){

        $('#Aceptar').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        var values = [['Title', $('#titulo').val()], ['Descripci_x00f3_n', $('#descripcion').val()], 
            ['Tipo_x0020_Incidencia', $('#tipo').val()], ['Prioridad', $('#prioridad').val()], ['Estado', 'Abierta']];

        $().SPServices({
            operation: "UpdateListItems",
            async: false,
            batchCmd: "New",
            webURL: targetUrl,
            listName: listName,
            valuepairs: values,
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                if (Status == 'success') {
                    if ($(xData).hasSPError()) {
                        alert("Sucedió un error: " + $(xData).getSPError());
                    } else {
                        alert("Incidencia creada con identificador: " + $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").attr("ows_ID") );

                        $('#titulo').val('');
                        $('#descripcion').val('');
                        $('#tipo').val('');
                        $('#prioridad').val('');

                        $('#Aceptar').removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("No se pudo contactar con el servidor");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I use to call REST like this in my current project:

```
var formDigest =  $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your URL here",
    headers: { "X-RequestDigest": formDigest },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "ParamName": "Param Value" }),
    datatype: 'json',
})
.done(function (data) {
   // success way
})
.fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
   // error way
});
```